# Select related entity from query rather than the main entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

This is a query to favourite fields

```
public IEnumerable<Field> GetAllFavouriteFieldsRelatedToUser(
    int page, 
    int amount, 
    string sort, 
    string order, 
    ISearchCriteria searchCriteria, 
    string userID)
{
    return context.FavouriteFields
                  .Select( x => x.Field )
                  .Where( x => x.CreatedBy.Id == userID )
                  .Skip( ( page - 1 ) * amount )
                  .Take( amount );
}
```

I want it to return the field it is actually related to, rather than the favourite field entity... thus the Select query. However, this does not work.

How do I go about achieving this?

Comment: What error are you getting? You should be using `IQueryable<>` instead of `IEnumerable<>` when working with EF queries unless it is very clear that no further operations will be used on the returned query.

Comment: @Johnbot - That's why it's returning IEnumerable :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must put `Select` last or after `Where` based on your requirements:

```
context.FavouriteFields
    .Where(x => x.CreatedBy.Id == userID) // Filter table where CreatedBy.Id equals to userId
    .Skip((page - 1) * amount) // Skips some amount of data and returns IQuerable<FavouriteField>
    .Take(amount) // Takes some amount of data and returns IQuerable<FavouriteField>
    .Select(x => x.Field); // Selects Field entity
```

Comment: Would also be useful to improve the answer to explain why the select should be last (e.g. the chaining and what types are available to each method as the chain is executed)

Comment: It's not required to put `.Select` last, just to put it after the `.Where`.

Comment: Helpful to know Richard!